# Error while running the compute statistics code in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I was running a code in MATLAB regarding statistics. Everything was going good until the following error occurred. The mu inputs are not linked anywhere else before and are used for the first time. Then I faced this error. I don't know where to make correction to solve it.
here is the code:

```
IT_n(1:LinkNum,1)  = NaN; % number of interarrival times (IT)
IT_mu(1:LinkNum,1)  = NaN; % mean of IT
IT_std(1:LinkNum,1) = NaN; % std of IT
IT_cov(1:LinkNum,1) = NaN; % cov of IT

for i = 1:LinkNum
    art  = L_arrival{i,1};            % yrs, arrival time
    art  = art(art>(PSWFmx(i,1)+mu)); % use data greater than PSWFi+mu
    sart = sort(art);                 % sorted arrival time
    iart = diff(sart);                % interarrival time

    IT_n(i,1)   = length(iart);           % number of interarrival times (IT)
    IT_mu(i,1)  = mean(iart);             % mean of IT
    IT_std(i,1) = std(iart);              % std of IT
    IT_cov(i,1) = IT_std(i,1)/IT_mu(i,1); % cov of IT

    clear art sart iart
end
```

Comment: Your function needs to set all of the values in the return: bnds, rowd, etc.  Also next time, please copy & paste the code rather than pasting an image.

Comment: Which error are you talking about? Could you reference it?